# Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

Getting the below error while deploying the project in weblogic server 10.3.6 for the first time using eclipse.

Below is the error captured in the console.

```
<Error> <org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader> <BEA-000000> <Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehCacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1868)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at java.beans.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:1272)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1270)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1136)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:387)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptorInternal(BeanWrapperImpl.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.isWritableProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1868)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at java.beans.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:1272)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1270)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1136)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:387)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptorInternal(BeanWrapperImpl.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.isWritableProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1868)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
> 
<Apr 16, 2014 6:40:07 PM IST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehCacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheException.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehCacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at java.beans.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:1272)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Apr 16, 2014 6:40:08 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1397653701941' for task '0'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: '
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Apr 16, 2014 6:40:08 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 1 task for the application 'EMWLS'.> 
<Apr 16, 2014 6:40:08 PM IST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'EMWLS'.> 
<Apr 16, 2014 6:40:08 PM IST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Web.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>eHIS Application</display-name>

    <description>
        eHIS web Application
    </description>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


<!-- Start Spring Definition for Spring Modules -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
<!-- End Spring Definition for Spring Modules -->
<!-- Start Register SpringCacheBean as ServletContextListener -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.ehis.persist.SpringCacheBean
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
<!-- End Register SpringCacheBean as ServletContextListener -->

        <session-config>
        <session-timeout>600</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>LOCAL_EJBS</param-name>
        <param-value>TRUE</param-value>
    </context-param>
...
....
```

applicationContext.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">


        <bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:ehcache.xml</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="httpSessionCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
            <property name="cacheManager">
                <ref local="ehCacheManager"/>
            </property>
            <property name="cacheName">
                <value>http.session.cache</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="messageCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
            <property name="cacheManager">
                <ref local="ehCacheManager"/>
            </property>
            <property name="cacheName">
                <value>message.cache</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="labelCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
            <property name="cacheManager">
                <ref local="ehCacheManager"/>
            </property>
            <property name="cacheName">
                <value>label.cache</value>
            </property>
        </bean>


</beans>
```

Please review and suggest..

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Is EhCache on your classpath? If not, are you using Maven or Gradle?

Answer (score 1):

you need **[ehcache-x.x.x.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache)** to be available in `CLASSPATH`

**Note:** If you have used Spring 3.0, Spring's EhCache support requires [EhCache 1.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/1.3.0) or higher. As of Spring 3.2, recommended to use EhCache 2.1 or higher.